# dualboot- installer cant see the hard drive

Tags: dual-boot

I want to dual boot my acer swift 3, but the installer of ubuntu 18.04 and 18.10 does not see my hard drive. I have fast startup and secure boot disabled. What should i do?
thanks for your answer and sorry for bad english.

Answer (score 0):

In order to rectify your problem, you need to first reboot your system with Ubuntu USB stick(or CD/DVD) in live mode.
Then open the disk utility app in your Ubuntu and check if your hard disk is visible there or not (you will most probably found it there), if not then try to refresh a couple of time and see if your hard disk is listed.
Also, try the following command :

```
$fdisk -l
```

This will list all the partitions on your hard disk.

Once you find your hard disk listed, unmount it once and then again mount it and then start the Installation process normally in live mode.

If the above methods are not helping you then it might be a corrupted USB stick or Ubuntu image file, try rebooting the Ubuntu on the stick with "USB universal installer" or some other software and then try installing Ubuntu on your system OR try downloading the Ubuntu image once again.

Also, make sure you have created some unallocated space in your previously installed system to allocate that memory to the ubuntu oS.

"GParted is a good partitioning tool which could be used for checking your hard disk and partitioning it."
Enjoy...

Comment: disk utility and fdisk -l sees it normally im gonna try, thanks